# Exporting attribute data from vector data by selecting object in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, select-by-attribute

I'm using QGIS (2.4.0), and i need to export the attribute data of the object i select (shapefile) to another file ( Excel, txt,...it is yet to be determined depending on the solution).
I know how it is done manually, but this action has to be done over a thousand times, and it can only be done one object at a time...
I'm looking for a automated proces where just by selecting a object the attribute data is written on the fly into the other file.

Does anyone have a solution, or an easy workaround, for this?